# Visited-links are too low-contrast

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, hyperlinks

Visited links on the site are a dark blue that has very low contrast with the surrounding black text. This isn't a problem in post bodies since links are dotted-underlined (except in post preview, oddly), but visited links tend to disappear in comments.

I'm a visually-typical individual, and even I have a hard time seeing a visited link when I *know* it's there (because I just made the comment). It won't often be a problem of course since to "disappear" a link a user has to visit it first, but some of us like to have our browsers keep our visited-link history for a *very* long time, and it's contrary to web design best practices to make visited links visually disappear anyway. I'm sure it's a bug or oversight (judging from the extra styling on in-post links)—could it be fixed?

A screenshot illustrates how there's hardly any contrast in luminance or colour between the regular and link text:

[image: Plain text and hyperlinked text example]

Comment: for reference the color of visited links in hex is: #114475

Comment: [status-completed] by an SE Dev on the duplicate, following suit here.

Answer (score -4):

You could use a browser extension, such as [StyleBot for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha), to alter the CSS of the website more to your liking. You can make visited links any color using the CSS:

```
a:visited { color: pink !important }
```

Comment: I could, but that doesn't make it less of a bug that deserves to be reported here. That wouldn't fix it for anyone else using the site.

Comment: It is my personal opinion that the colors are currently fine, which is why I recommended an external solution.

Comment: Then that's more of a comment, not an answer to the bug report. Thanks though.

Comment: I agree with sevensideddie btw, I find all the link colors hard to see. I see it often when I try to proofread my answers. I sometimes miss my own links.

Comment: I still don't agree that an opinion counts as a bug, though. I have no issues with them.

Comment: You may be more familiar with software bugs? Designs can contain bugs too.

Comment: That doesn't mean that what you've pointed out is a bug. If the developers consider this to be the intended look, then your opinion that it is a "flaw" is irrelevant. The links look different than regular text. The amount of difference is personal preference.

Comment: Or maybe UX isn't actually personal preference.